# Question on .this binding within a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

**Goal:** During a `.this()` binding within a React component, I want to fully understand the reference that is being made and the EXACT step-by-step process the computer takes.

**Description:** I have some code (listed directed below), within the code the computer is binding the `handleChange` input handler via the line `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`. There is a parent component `MyApp` which has a child component `GetInput` and another child component `RenderInput`.

**Questions:**

Question 1. My confusion primarily stems from thinking that `.this()` automatically references the closest "parent" object and that binding via `.this()` would thus redirect it to the closest parent object of where `.bind()` is written. In the case below, it appears to redirect to the `MyApp` component. However, the `MyApp` class is a function `console.log(typeof MyApp) //expected: function`. As such, why is `.this()` not referencing the global object in the code below?

Question 2. What are the step-by-step processes that the computer makes when the handleChange handler is called? Is it the following:

1. Initial call within the `RenderInput` component: `<p>{this.props.input}</p>`
2. Referencing `RenderInput` parent which is the `GetInput` component: `<input value={this.props.input} onChange={this.props.handleChange}/></div>`
3. The computer reads `onChange={this.props.handleChange}`
4. Goes to the `GetInput` component's parent which is the `MyApp` component and reads: `handleChange={this.handleChange}` *(this is the step that I am most unsure of)*
5. Finding where `.this()` is bound to: `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`
6. Referencing `MyApp` as the binding value of `this`
7. Executing the `handleChange` handler: `handleChange(event) {this.setState({inputValue: event.target.value });}`

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: event.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          <GetInput
            input={this.state.inputValue}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        }
        {
          <RenderInput input={this.state.inputValue} />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class GetInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Get Input:</h3>
        <input
          value={this.props.input}
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class RenderInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Input Render:</h3>
        <p>{this.props.input}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start from the fact that behaviour of neither `this` nor `.bind` is React specific. So, for the sake of simplicity, let's just temporarily forget about React & just look at some vanilla JS code (no worries! We will get back to React later on).

Now let's start from the very start, this is an object:

```js
{
  username: "KamiFightingSpirit"
}
```

Seems easy, but object's values might be whatever (arrays, other objects, functions, etc.). Let's also add a function:

```js
{
  username: "KamiFightingSpirit",
  logUsername: function () {
    console.log( this.username );
  }
}
```

What the hell is `this`? `this` refers to execution context, you might also have heard:

> `this`/execution context is anything before the dot that precedes function call.

Let's quickly check it out, having in mind that `this` is not the same as scope. It's calculated during the execution.

```js
const soUser = {
  username: "KamiFightingSpirit",
  logUsername: function () {
    console.log(this.username);
  }
};

soUser.logUsername();
// -> KamiFightingSpirit
```

All right, during the execution `this` was equal to `soUser`.

```js
// Let's just borrow the method from soUser
const userNameLogger = soUser.logUsername;

const nestedObjects = {
  username: "This property will not be logged", // neither "KamiFightingSpirit" will be logged
  sampleUser: {
    username: "Igor Bykov",
    logUsername: userNameLogger
  }
};

nestedObjects.sampleUser.logUsername();
// -> Igor Bykov
```

Nice, it worked again. `this` was equal to the object before the dot that precedes function call. In this case, the object was `nestedObjects.sampleUser`'s value.

Note again that execution context doesn't work like scope. If the used property is missing in the object before the dot, a check for existence in the parent will not be performed. Here is the same example, but with `username` missing:

```js
const nestedObjects = {
  username: "undefined will be logged",
  sampleUser: {
    logUsername: userNameLogger
  }
};

nestedObjects.sampleUser.logUsername();
// -> undefined
```

We're half way there. Now, how do we create a lot of users programatically?

```js
// this is called constructor function
function User(name) {
  // const this = {}; <- implicitly when used with "new" keyword
  this.name = name;
  // return this; <- implicitly when used with "new" keyword
}

console.log( new User("LonelyKnight") );
// -> {name: "LonelyKnight"}
```

Here `new` forces creation of a new object (and, hence, an execution content).

However, creating objects this way is quite dangerous. If you call the same function without `new`, it will execute but new object will not be created and `this` will be evaluated to `window` object. This way we will effectively assign `name` to `window`.

Because of that and couple of reasons more, in newer versions of JavaScript `class` was introduced. Classes do precisely the same as constructor functions (in fact, they *are* smarter & nicer constructor functions).

So, the following example is **very** similar to the previous one:

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;   
  }
}
```

We're almost there! Now let's say, we also want to be able to change user names.

```js
class User {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;   
  }

  changeName(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }

}

let batman = new User("Bat");
console.log(batman.name); // -> Bat
batman.changeName("Batman!");
console.log(batman.name); // -> Batman!
```

cool, it works! Note that we haven't used no `.bind`. It's not necessary in this case since we perform everything on the instance of the class.

Now, let's go back to React. In React we tend to pass *functions* (**not** instances) from parents to children. As I said before, classes are very much like smart constructor functions. So, let's first see what our code would look like if we used constructor functions instead of classes for each component.

If we throw away all JSX and synthetic sugar that React adds, the operation that is performed would look pretty similar to something like:

```js
function Child(f) {
  // Random property
  this.rand = "A";
  f(); // -> Window
}

function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.logThis = function(){
    console.log(this);
  }
  this.render = function(){
    return new Child(this.logThis);
  }
}

// Somewhere in React internals (in overly-simplified constructor-based universe)
const U = new User(``);
U.render();
```

Note that since we just call `f()`, there's no dot before it, and hence, there's no context in which `f()` is executed. In this cases, (unless strict mode is set), `this` is evaluated to global object which is `Window` in browsers.

Now, let's get back to classes & write something very similar:

```js
// Child component
class Child {

  constructor(f) {
    setTimeout(
      () => f("Superman"), // -> throws "Cannot set "name" of undefined"
      100
    );
  }

}

// Parent component
class User {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  changeName(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }

  render() {
   return new Child(this.changeName);
  }

}

// Somewhere in React internals (in overly-simplified universe)
const batman = new User("batman");
batman.render();
```

Since classes [use strict mode by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Strict_mode), the example above seeing nothing before `f()`, evaluates `this` to undefined, tries to assign new property to undefined and throws error failing to do so.

So, to avoid this, we need to use `.bind` or similar function in order to ensure that it'll always be executed in the right context.

What exactly does `.bind` do? [Some internal black magic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Description). To fully understand it, you probably need to dig into a JS compiler code (normally written in C/C++).

However, there's an easier option. MDN (being an awesome site it is) [offers you ready-to-use polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) that basically show how `.bind` might be re-written in vanilla JS. If you see it closely, you'll notice that both polyfills just wrap calls to `.apply` or `.call`. So, the interesting part is actually not "disclosed".

I guess that the reason for that is that internal C++/C magic might not be faithfully reproduced with JS since we don't have access to internal mechanism.

However, if we'd be about to reproduce `.bind` functionality at least badly, we'd find out that `.bind` is not that complex (at least at basic level), it's main functionality is just to ensure that execution context always stays the same.

Here is a dead bad implementation of `.customBind` in its easiest form:

```
Function.prototype.customBind = function(obj, ...bindedArgs) {
  // Symbol ensures our key is unique and doesn't re-write anything
  const fnKey = Symbol();
  // Inserts function directly into the object
  obj[fnKey] = this;
  // Return a wrapper that just calls the function
  // from within specified object each time it's called.
  return (...args) => obj[fnKey](...bindedArgs, ...args);
};
```

While it works, the downside here is that we actually insert our function into the object. While we could hide it better with `Object.defineProperty`, it still would be there.

Here is a more involved way which could mutate the original object anyway but only the way you would expect it to (this implementation isn't any better than the previous one though. It's only a hypothetical example):

```js
// Please, never use this code for anything practical
// unless you REALLY understand what you are doing.

// Implements customBind
Function.prototype.customBind = function(context, ...bindedArgs) {
  // context => intended execution context
  // bindedArgs => original .bind also accept those
  // Saves function that should be binded into a variable
  const fn = this;
  // Returns a new function. Original .bind also does.
  return (...args) => {

    // Symbol is used to ensure that
    // fn's key will not unintentionally
    // re-writte something in the original
    // object.
    const fnSymbol = Symbol();

    // Since we can't directly manipulate
    // execution context (not doable in JS),
    // neither we can just call "context.fn()" since
    // .fn is not in context's prototype chain,
    // the best thing we can do is to dinamically
    // mock execution context, so, we'll be able to
    // run our binded function, inside the mocked
    // context.
    const contextClone = {
        ...context,
        // adds binded function into a
        // clone of its intended execution
        // context.
        [fnSymbol]: fn,
    };
  
    // Executes binded function inside the exact clone
    // of its intended execution context & saves returned
    // value. We will return it to the callee
    // later on.
    const output = contextClone[fnSymbol](...bindedArgs, ...args);
    // Deletes property, so, it'll not leak into
    // the original object on update that we're
    // going to perform.
    delete contextClone[fnSymbol];
    // The function that we've run on our clone, might
    // possibly change something inside the object it
    // operated upon. However, since the object it
    // operated upon is just a mock that we've created,
    // the original object will stay unchanged. In order
    // to avoid such a situation, let's merge our possibly
    // changed clone into the original object.
    context = Object.assign(context, contextClone);
    // Finally, let's return to the callee,
    // the result returned by binded function.
    return output;
  };
};

// Let's test it works!
const soUser = {
    name: `Kami`,
    logName: function() {
        console.log(`My name is ${this.name}`);
    },
    changeName: function(newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    },
};

// Let's just borrow these methods from soUser
const soUserOwnedLogger = soUser.logName.customBind(soUser);
const soUserNameChanger = soUser.changeName.customBind(
  soUser,
  "KamiFightingSpirit"
);

// Let's use borrowed methods into another object.
const outterSystemUser = {
    name: `UU-B235`,
    soUserLogger: soUserOwnedLogger,
    soUserChange: soUserNameChanger,
};


soUserOwnedLogger();
outterSystemUser.soUserChange();
soUserOwnedLogger();
console.log(`"name" in soUuser: ${soUser.name}`);
console.log(`"name" in outterSystemUser: ${outterSystemUser.name}`);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: [@KamiFightingSpirit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12457533/kamifightingspirit), if you are still curious, how `.bind` might work internally, I've updated the answer with some hypothetical way to write your own `.bind`! :)

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `this` in the example below:

```
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: event.target.value
    });
  }
```

is referring to the parent function `handleChange` and `handleChange` does not a have `setState` method. What does is the component when we extend `class MyApp extends React.Component`. It is 'inheriting' `setState` from `React.Component`... which is why we have to manually bind it to that class (which is just syntactic sugar, under the hood as you pointed out it is a function...)

Going deeper: When you create a constructor function like so:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
```

And then you call that function with the new keyword like so:

```
const personOne = new Person('Bob', 26)
```

What happens under the hood is the keyword `new` creates an empty object and sets `this` as its reference, which is why in the function body itself we have `this.name = name` etc...

You can think of it as something like so:

```
const this = {}

this.name = 'Bob'
this.age = 26
```

`this` would now be an object like `{ name: 'Bob', age: 26 }`

As a side note: in many examples, you will simply see an arrow function like so:

```
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: event.target.value
    });
  }
```

And that's because an arrow function does not have its own `this` context... It will automatically bubble up to the parent and there is no need to bind...